# doveadm replication fails with doveadm: Fatal: setuid(XX(banjo) from userdb lookup) failed with euid=8(mail): Operation not permitted (This binary

Tags: dovecot

I've been running postfix & dovecot on separate VMs mounting /var/mail over NFS, and trying to replicate with mailsync, but I get a lot of email duplication so I really want to get dsync working on dovecot.

I followed the advice at the following [blog](https://jarasyola.blogspot.com/2016/09/replicating-emails-between-two-mail.html) to get 95% of the configuration correct. As postfix was using user/group=mail/mail and I got errors about that, I did change vmail to mail in the config files (also vmail wasn't added to the passwd file by dnf).

The one problem which seems tiny is that I get the following error every time dsync runs:

```
Local:
Mar 20 23:10:19 doveadm(banjo): Error: doveadm server disconnected before handshake: EOF
Mar 20 23:10:19 doveadm(banjo): Error: sync: Disconnected from remote: EOF
Remote:
Mar 20 23:11:06 doveadm: Fatal: setuid(XXXX(banjo) from userdb lookup) failed with euid=8(mail): Operation not permitted (This binary should probably be called with process user set to XXXX(banjo) instead of 8(mail))
```

The closest match I've found to this error suggests running dovecot as root, but doveadm processes already run as root. Furthermore, when I connect via IMAP dovecot has no problem reading/writing mail Inboxes and folders (everything has g+rws and group mail for postfix to work).

Has anyone got any other ideas for troubleshooting or even a better blog?

PS: Both VMs are - Fedora 33, kernel 5.9.16-200, dovecot-2.3.13-2, HW=qemu-kvm-5.1.0-9.fc33.x86_64 on HP Proliant MicroServers (one Microserver is Gen9 the other Gen10)

TIA Banjo.

Answer (score 0):

Oops, when editing the username from vmail to mail, I accidentally added an extra line which was the cause.

```
service doveadm {
>>  user = mail  <<
    inet_listener {
        # port to listen on
        port = 12345
        # enable SSL
        #ssl = yes
    }
}
```

Now I have other problems.